# Import python module NOT on path

Tags: python, import, external, python-module

I have a module foo, containing util.py and bar.py.

I want to import it in IDLE or python session. How do I go about this?

I could find no documentation on how to import modules not in the current directory or the default python PATH.
After trying `import "<full path>/foo/util.py"`,
and `from "<full path>" import util`

The closest I could get was

```
import imp
imp.load_source('foo.util','C:/.../dir/dir2/foo')
```

Which gave me Permission denied on windows 7.

Comment: Also worth checking out this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109548/set-pythonpath-before-import-statements). In particular, I like the [top answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15109660/95852) there, for its clarity about the safety of changes to `sys.path`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a module given the full path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

One way is to simply amend your [path](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/full/path')
from foo import util,bar
```

Note that this requires foo to be a python package, i.e. contain a `__init__.py` file. If you don't want to modify `sys.path`, you can [also modify the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) or [install the module on your system](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html). Beware that this means that other directories or `.py` files in that directory may be loaded inadvertently.

Therefore, you may want to use [`imp.load_source`](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html#imp.load_source) instead. It needs the filename, not a directory (to a file which the current user is allowed to read):

```
import imp
util = imp.load_source('util', 'C:/full/path/foo/util.py')
```

Comment: It works, but now when trying to use util.method by using method, it says 'method' not defined. But I can use it by util.method. Why?

Comment: Because you haven't defined `method`, only "the `method` in `util`". You can define `method = util.method` if you want.

Comment: Note that `from foo import *` is bad coding unless you're just hacking around in the shell.

Comment: @katrielalex Thanks. And I'm using from foo import util, not from foo import *. So don't worry ;)

Comment: @Vort3x Well, that makes `util` available in your namespace. Why do you expect `util.method` to be available under the name `method`? That would mean that you'd have to ensure that there's not another `method` in `bar`, and thereby defeat the whole point of a module system, i.e. not having to worry about name collisions.

Comment: @Wooble Corrected to *package*. `__init__.py` **is** required. Observe `mkdir foo; touch foo/util.py; python -c 'from foo import util'` and `touch foo/__init__.py; python -c 'from foo import util'`

Comment: -1 Because appending to the Python path is a *bad* solution. It works, but it's strictly worse than `imp.load_source` because the user may not want to modify any system paths, or may be working on a computer where she or he cannot do so. This is actually one of the most annoying "features" in Python, which otherwise is an elegant language. It's silly that you can't just give `import` a string naming a path to another .py file. And given that you can't, protecting against changing system paths by using `imp` is *strictly* better.

Comment: @EMS The Python documentation [explicitly mentions `sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path). If the user cannot modify `sys.path`, it's extremely likely that the `imp` module is blocked as well (note that Python's `sys.path` has nothing with the [system's `PATH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))). Personally, I don't think that loading modules by name instead of filename is silly; it allows system-wide installations of Python packages (for example, on 2.5 you may want to serve your alternative `json` module). Added a cautionary note.

Comment: Well, yes, to import from a package you do need `__init__.py`, although if `<full path>/foo` were added to sys.path without it, then `import util` and `import bar` would both work. (changed vote to +1)

Answer (score 5):

You could customize the module search path using the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, or manually modify the `sys.path` directory list.

See [Module Search Path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) documentation on python.org.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try

```
import sys
sys.path.append('c:/.../dir/dir2')
import foo
```

Comment: -1 Because appending to the Python path is a bad solution. It works, but it's strictly worse than imp.load_source because the user may not want to modify any system paths, or may be working on a computer where she or he cannot do so. This is actually one of the most annoying "features" in Python, which otherwise is an elegant language. It's silly that you can't just give import a string naming a path to another .py file. And given that you can't, protecting against changing system paths by using imp is strictly better.

Comment: @EMS Ah .. I see what you are saying, I didn't realize it before, but now the point you make is clear. Thanks for pointing this out. (I may have to modify some of my own code now :)

Comment: Don't worry. This is the intended purpose of `sys.path` (or at least *an* intended use case). Mr. F (who apparently was previously EMS) is wrong. As phihag notes in his response to the identical -1 comment on his answer, `sys.path` is *not* related to the overall system path.

Comment: @ely It seems that imp.load_source (load_module) is deprecated after python3.3 what can be the alternative?

Comment: after importing foo, do a sys.path.pop() if you are worried about messing other imports up.

Comment: @zviad saw this many years later - there is [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009932/import-arbitrary-python-source-file-python-3-3) which shows workarounds and changes for newer versions of Python

Answer (score 2):

Following phihag's tip, I have this solution. Just give the path of a source file to `load_src` and it will load it. You must also provide a name, so you can import this module using this name. I prefer to do it this way because it's more explicit:

```
def load_src(name, fpath):
    import os, imp
    return imp.load_source(name, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fpath))

load_src("util", "../util.py")
import util

print util.method()
```

Another (less explicit) way is this:

```
util = load_src("util", "../util.py")    # "import util" is implied here

print util.method()    # works, util was imported by the previous line
```

*Edit:* the method is rewritten to make it clearer.