# Python : How to import user defined packages from any location?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to import packages in python . Below mentioned is my folder structure

```
MainFolder
      |config| locator|logs|page|tests
```

Each folder has `__init__.py` file .  tests folder has `test.py`. Now , inside `test.py` i am trying to import files from folders - config| locator|logs
 However python is not recognizing them as package. If I place them under `C:\Python27\Lib` then I am able to import.

I tried adding `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("/ MainFolder/<folder name>"))` before importing but it is not working.
How do I import them ?

Comment: You will need to add the location of the desired modules to your python path. From within your test script you can do that by appending the path to the each dependency you need. Note howerver that other python scripts will not benefit from this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109548/set-pythonpath-before-import-statements As a more permanent fix, you could try adding those dependencies to your PYTHONPATH. How to do that depends on which OS you are running.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am using windows. code_byter's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the solution:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/application/app/folder')
```

from [Importing files from different folder in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python)

Comment: No problem. Please do tick it as answer so it helps the rest of the community :)