# Importing external module in single-file exe created with PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am using PyInstaller to create a single-file executable. Is it possible for my script to perform an import such that i) the imported module is imported from the same directory as the exe (i.e. it's not packaged into the exe) and ii) that imported module can import other modules that *were* packaged into the exe?

The background here is that the imported module contains configuration that the user should be able to modify. This may include creation of custom derived classes and use of enums from the packaged modules.

I haven't found any advice on this, though it's a difficult search because there are so many similar topics that use basically the same keywords.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following steps allow a Python module (named `external_module` here) outside of an executable created by PyInstaller to be imported and for that module to import modules that were bundled into the executable.

- Add `excludes=['external_module']` to the Analysis object used in the PyInstaller spec. This prevents `external_module.py` being bundled into the executable.
- Add `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))` where `external_module` is imported in your application. This allows it to be imported from the directory the executable is in, which is different to the directory that the application will run in (due to being decompressed to a temporary folder). See below for my recommended method of achieving this.
- Make sure any imports performed by `external_module.py` are also performed by one of the bundled modules *before* `external_module.py` is imported. The interpreter *will not* resolve the external module's imports against bundled modules, but *will* use ones that already exist in `sys.modules`.

In order to set up the paths correctly you can use the following:

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    app_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    sys.path.append(app_path)
else:
    app_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

`frozen` is only available in generated executables, not when running as a script directly. This snippet will add the executable's location to `sys.path` if required as well as giving you easy access to the executable or script's location for use in code.

As an example of the final bullet point, consider the following.

```
# bundled_module1.py
import external_module
```

```
# bundled_module2.py
# module content
```

```
# external_module.py
import bundled_module2
```

This will fail in `external_module.py` because `bundled_module2` can't be found. However, the following modification to `bundled_module1.py` will work:

```
# bundled_module1.py
import bundled_module2
import external_module
```

This will be fine if there are a limited set of bundled modules that the external one should be able to import. It may get unwieldy for larger sets.

Given that the documentation states that the interpreter *will* resolve imports against modules bundled into the executable, this feels like a possible bug. Interoperating with modules outside of the executable isn't explicitly called out though.

Answer (score 0):

Type in `Pyinstaller -h`.  It will give you info about pyinstaller and tell you about `--runtime-hook`.  I presume adding this to the executable should work.  There's actually a whole page of [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/hooks.html) for this. Surprised you could not find that.

Anyway,

The docs say put in:
`pyinstaller --additional-hooks-dir=. myscript.py`.

I presume then something like `pyinstaller --additional-hooks-dir=C:\pathtofolder myscript.py` should work in theory.  Yet to test it.  Tell us how it goes and what made kinks made it work for you.

Lastly, if you want to be hipster try integrating cython for speed and obfuscation.  Fair warning, cython is not as user friendly as pyinstaller appears to be.  I have yet to use it successfully.

Comment: I did find the hooks documentation, but it looked like it was focused on allowing pyinstaller to find (and bundle) modules imported in odd ways that it would otherwise miss. I'm trying to do the opposite. I'll take another look at that though and see if it's useful.

Comment: @Kemp Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109548/set-pythonpath-before-import-statements .  It's a nifty workaround.  Yet to try it myself, but I may use it in the future.  It would mean your files would be exposed though, so probably a last resort.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Progress so far: i) Added `excludes=['config']` to the Analysis object used in my PyInstaller spec. This prevents config.py being bundled. ii) Added `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))` where I import the config. This allows it to be imported from the directory the exe is in.
Still left to figure out: i) Allowing config.py to import modules that were bundled up. They don't exist in any free-floating form in the temporary execution directory and the interpreter doesn't seem to resolve imports against the bundled modules.

Comment: I've added an answer with the solution I ended up using. Any further comments are welcome.