# Creating a Python module with its dependencies self contained

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

When creating a Python module, you can specify dependencies of your module by using the `install_requires` List.

Lets look at this basic example.

```
setup(name='some_module',
      version='0.0.1',
      packages=find_packages(),
      install_requires=[
          'requests==2.21.0'
      ])
```

I package my module `python3 setup.py sdist` and upload it to a package repository.

But when I go to install `pip3 install some_module==0.0.1` it will install `requests==2.21.0` globally in my python3 `site-packages/`.

To my question, how do I get similar functionality to npm, with nested `node_modules/` where my Python module would have its *own* `site-packages/` and it would reference its local version of `requests` instead of overwriting my global version.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this fixed by virtual environments?

Comment: @roganjosh I think not because different versions of a given package can be in different `node_modules` folders at the same level of nesting. As far as I know that's not how venv works

Comment: @charleslandau I'll buy that npm is outside of my comfort zone, but a single package running multiple versions of a library? Does this exist?

Comment: @roganjosh no I mean separate packages. As in pkg1 requires axiosv1.0.1 and pg2 requires axios1.1.1

Comment: I don't think Python's import model supports that kind of nesting.

Comment: I think I'll have to build my own nesting method, and specifically install the dependencies locally, and add it to the system path ahead of the normal locations.

I have a very specific use case, where we have projects that use 2 custom modules, and 1 of those custom modules relies itself on the other. It's a little hairy.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for this task!

Directly from the Pyinstaller's documentation:

*PyInstaller **bundles a Python application and all its dependencies into a single package.** The user can run the packaged app without installing a Python interpreter or any modules. PyInstaller supports Python 2.7 and Python 3.4+, and correctly bundles the major Python packages such as numpy, PyQt, Django, wxPython, and others.*

You can install it with a simple pip install:

```
pip install PyInstaller
```

For a more detailed tutorial check out this [link](https://realpython.com/pyinstaller-python/)

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks this is a great idea. Will look into it more, on the surface I'm not sure if this is going to solve my problem, as the module will need to be imported and run from the context of a normal python framework. I've only skimmed the docs, will report back.

Comment: Maybe you could add the executable created by Pyinstaller to your Python path. Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350078/importing-external-module-in-single-file-exe-created-with-pyinstaller since it's somewhat similar. In the past I used Pyinstaller to create an executable for a project written in python so I could create a npm wrapper so front end devs could just npm install my project without having to deal with python. Best of luck!