# Is it possible to import a built pyinstaller executable into a python script?

Tags: python, python-import, pyinstaller

Is it possible to import a built pyinstaller package within a python script?

For example I have run pyinstaller on the following script:

`count_to_ten.py`

```
def count():
   for i in range(10):
      print(i)
```

I've then packaged this with pyinstaller using `pyinstaller -F count_to_ten.py` to produce an executable `count_to_ten.exe`

I know that I can import `count_to_ten.py` using `import count_to_ten` and then call `count()` as needed.

Is there any equivalent way I can do this using the "built" pyinstaller file other than executing this using `exec` or `subprocess`?

Ideally something equivalent to:

`main.py`

```
import count_to_ten.exe

count_to_ten.count()
```

**Edit**
It was suggested that the solution "[Importing external module in single-file exe created with PyInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350078/importing-external-module-in-single-file-exe-created-with-pyinstaller)" resolves this question. The suggested solution solves the opposite problem.

The above solution involves importing external `.py` files into a single-file-exe created by pyinstaller. I want to import single-file-exe files into an interpreted `.py` script without using `exec` or `subprocess`.