# Dynamically importing .py files after compiling

Tags: python, python-module, compiled

I've tried looking online and I'm honestly lost at this point.

I'm trying to find if there's a way to import python scripts and run them AFTER my Python program has been compiled.

For an example, let's say I have a `main.py` such that:

```
import modules.NewModule

a = NewModuleClass()
a.showYouWork()
```

then I compile `main.py` with `pyinstaller` so that my directory looks like:

```
main.exe
modules/NewModule.py
```

My end goal is to make a program that can dynamically read new Python files in a folder (this will be coded in) and use them (the part I'm struggling with). I know it's possible, since that's how add-ons work in Blender 3D but I've struggled for many hours to figure this out. I think I'm just bad at choosing the correct terms in Google.

Maybe I just need to convert all of the Python files in the modules directory to `.pyc` files? Then, how would I use them?

Also, if this is a duplicate on here (it probably is), please let me know. I couldn't find this issue on this site either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing external module in single-file exe created with PyInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350078/importing-external-module-in-single-file-exe-created-with-pyinstaller)

Comment: Wow! Fast! I'm not sure. I'll try this out and get back to you. Hopefully it works well! Actually heading to bed now. I didn't expect to have a response this quickly.

Comment: do you mean like programs use dll files

Answer (score 0):

You may find no detailed answer simply because there is no problem. `PyInstaller` does not really compile Python scripts into machine code executables. It just *assembles* then into a folder along with an embedded Python interpretor, or alternatively creates a compressed single file executable that will automatically uncompress itself at run time into a temporary folder containing that.

From then on, you have an almost standard Python environment, with normal .pyc file which can contain normal Python instructions like calls to `importlib` to dynamically load other Python modules. You have just to append the directory containing the modules to `sys.path` before importing them. An other possible caveat, is that pyinstaller only gets required modules and not a full Python installation, so you must either make sure that the dynamic modules do not rely on missing standard modules, or be prepared to face an `ImportError`.

Comment: There are caveats that I discuss in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350078/importing-external-module-in-single-file-exe-created-with-pyinstaller