# Import libraries from ROOT directory in python

Tags: python, libraries

I have the following structure of my program:

```
MainDir
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
├── Routine.py
└── Folder1
    ├── __init__.py
    └──function.py
```

I know that I can import a function from `folder 1` to my `main.py` program writing this statement:

`from Folder1.function import foo`

But, I am looking for a way to do so in the other direction. How could I import a function defined in `Routine.py` to `function.py`?

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109548/set-pythonpath-before-import-statements

Comment: Also this: https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports

Comment: The first one worked for me. I imported `os library` to get my current working directory and then appended it to the `sys.path`

Comment: in `folder1/fucntion` you can write `from main.routine import function1`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are invoking your program.

#### Invoking as a module

Do you do something like

```
python -m MainDir.main
```

and whatever code is in your `MainDir.main` calls out to `MainDir/Folder1/function.py`?

In this case, you can simply add the following import to `MainDir/Folder1/function.py`:

```
from ..Routine import RoutineFunction
```

#### Invoking as a script

If you are instead invoking `MainDir/Folder1/function.py` as a script using:

```
python MainDir/Folder1/function.py
```

you will not be able to use relative imports as suggested above. There are still many options available to you, as described here: [How to import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files)

#### Suggested reading

Python imports can be very confusing. Here is a great post on the topic, which could be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/4905625