# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' - Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip, jupyter-notebook

I'm facing weird issue in my Jupyter-notebook.

In my first cell:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install numpy
!{sys.executable} -m pip install Pillow
```

In the second cell:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
```

But it says : **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'**

[image: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy']

I have used this command to install Jupyter notebook :

```
sudo apt install python3-notebook jupyter jupyter-core python-ipykernel
```

Additional information :

```
pip --version
pip 20.2.2 from /home/maifee/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
python --version
Python 3.7.5
```

Comment: Gosh, did you start the jupyter server as root? Otherwise its `! pip install --user`.

Comment: @Suuuehgi , thanks it worked...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @suuuehgi.
When Jupyter Notebook isn't opened as root:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install --user numpy
```

Answer (score 3):

I've had occasional weird install issues with Jupyter Notebooks as well when I'm running a particular virtual environment. Generally, installing with pip directly in the notebook in this form:

`!pip install numpy`

fixes it. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Lynn_Leifker, this was already outdated information when you posted it. Best practice at that point was already `%pip install numpy` for when installing directly in the notebook using pip. The modern magic commands were added to insure the install occurs in the correct environment. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the magic install commands added a few years ago. The exclamation point alone doesn't do that. See the ...

Comment: <continued> second paragraph [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) for more about why the exclamation point is not as good and can lead to issues.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the kernal from the Jupyter Notebook solved this issue for me

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Turns out I renamed an upstream path. And I hadn't deactivated my conda env first. When I deactivated the env.

```
conda deactivate
```

Then when I activated it again, everything was as it should have been.

```
conda activate sample
```

Now I am seeing other issues with jupyter themes... but its not impacting my numpy code. So, at least I fixed the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'" error

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. My numpy is installed, I am using the same folder as usual.
If I try 'conda deactivate', I get the message:
ValueError: The python kernel does not appear to be a conda environment.  Please use `%pip install` instead.
[I added a print of the 'pip install numpy' result and the 'Module not found error' after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf7il.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which worked for me:

```
lib_path="c:\\users\\user\\python_39\\lib\\site-packages\\"
MODULE_NAME = "module_to_import"
MODULE_PATH = lib_path+MODULE_NAME+"\\__init__.py"
import importlib
import sys
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(MODULE_NAME, MODULE_PATH)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules[spec.name] = module 
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
import module_to_import
```

Comment: There is simpler approach for you @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/15109660/1686903