# Python 3.10.4 Import "numpy" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)

Tags: numpy, jupyter-notebook, python-import, python-3.10, pylance

A simple Jupyter notebook code snippet run in VSCode on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
import numpy as np
def square(x):
    return x * x
```

Error: `Import "numpy" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)`

Answer (score 0):

[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy' - Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63756673/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-numpy-jupyter-notebook)

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install --user numpy
import numpy as np
def square(x):
    return x * x
```