# ModuleNotFoundError - No module named "numpy" after installing numpy from within Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pip

I'm trying to install numpy from within a Jupyter notebook. I've tried a couple of different approaches (in addition to installing directly from the terminal). The pattern that I usually get is:

1 - Pip3 says that it has successfully installed the package

2 - I check that numpy exists in the folder I'm installing to (it always does)

3 - `import numpy` gives a `ModuleNotFoundError`

This is the first approach I took:
[image: pip3 bork - angery!]

I also saw another SO post with a seemingly similar issue to mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63756673/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-numpy-jupyter-notebook). It recommends the following method of installing numpy from within Jupyter notebook:

[image]

Since my kernel is running v3.11.5

[image]

I thought that I might need to use pip3, but that doesn't work:
[image]

Some additional information:

I believe that pip3 (when run from my terminal) is installing packages for a different version of python (v3.12). I'm not sure how to verify this but IIRC I initially installed python v3.12 then installed a new version of python (v3.11) because a package was complaining about v3.12. This new version of python is being run from a different hard drive and I believe that this is the python version which is in use by Jupyter notebook.

Thanks to anyone who can help, this is a nightmare!

Edit: some more information about what happens when I install from the terminal:

[image]

Pip3 "successfully" installs, pip3 list then doesn't show numpy:

[image]

Comment: have you tried `pip install numpy` without specifying a path, so that it installs it in your default path?

Comment: Joe you're a star! This has worked and it has thankfully installed the package under E:\Python\Lib\site-packages. This is great as I really want all these packages installed on my E drive. Thank you :) If you want to put this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. You can post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6394617/joe), the issue was in me specifying a target directory.

I'm still not clear on what -t is useful for if python doesn't realise where it's installed but there we go.