# ImportError: No module named test2

Tags: python-2.7

I get that error message when I run `python testscript.py` I tried the recommendations given in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10161568/import-python-module-not-on-path) but was unsuccessful. My directory structure is as follows:

```
> bin
> - __init__.py
> - testscript.py
> 
> test2
> - __init__.py
> - printstring_module.py
```

And my code in `testscript.py` is as follows:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\Users\KMF\Exercises\Projects\kevin_game\test2')
from test2 import printstring_module

printstring_module.printstrings("this is a test")
print("test over")
```

And the code for `printstring_module.py` is as follows:

```
def printstrings(string="you didn't provide a string"):
    print(string)
```

When I place both `testscript.py` and `printstring_module.py` in the same directory eg. bin folder the code works just fine.

Thanks and happy new year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are included the folder test2 in your path, so you should use something like this:

```
from printstring_module import printstrings
```

And then use `printstrings` function directly:

```
printstrings("this is a test")
```

Also rename `init.py` to `__init__.py`

EDIT:
You should also scape `\` character. Try this code:

```
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\KMF\Exercises\Projects\kevin_game\test2')
```

Note `r` i included before the opening quote.

Comment: I just tried this and resulted in this error message `ImportError: No module named printstring_module`

Comment: Also you should have an empty `__init__.py` in your folder. I edited my post, check it @ferry

Comment: Hey my `__init__.py` are fine. Just that when I marked them as codes, SO removed the underscores. Code still doesn't work.

Comment: Put a `r` before the opening single quote to scape the `backslash` character. @ferry

Comment: Wow, that worked. Could you please explain to me what the r did?

Comment: Good, please mark it as answered :) When you put `r` before the string, you tell python to consider it as raw string, so you shouldn't scape \ character. instead of `r`, you can use something like this : `c:\\Users\\...`. @ferry